# Nothing happening when using express's static middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am following an example of using express's static middleware in the *express in action* book by Evan Hann.

Here is the code I wrote

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

// sets up the public path, using Node's path module
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    res.end("Look like you didn't find a static file.")
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Normally the application should serve me whatever is in the public directory. I put an image in the public folder (Twitter_32.png). But nothing is happening when I navigate to http://localhost:3000/.

What am I missing?

Here is the content of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "hello world example using expressjs",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "hello",
    "world",
    "express"
  ],
  "author": "Sandro Agboka",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my project directory structure

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 macbook staff   272 May  4 14:59 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 macbook staff   136 May  3 16:04 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 macbook staff  1155 May  3 17:48 app-old.js
-rw-r--r--   1 macbook staff   440 May  4 15:02 app.js
drwxr-xr-x 191 macbook staff  6494 May  3 17:40 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 macbook staff 53133 May  3 17:40 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--   1 macbook staff   465 May  3 17:40 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   3 macbook staff   102 May  4 14:59 public
```

Comment: Whats inside of `public/index.html` ?

Comment: no I put an image there : Twitter_32.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to navigate to the **full** resource path : `http://localhost:3000/Twitter_32.png`

Comment: It worked. I haven't understood the paragraph I was reading. Thank you.